# Parsing Google Sheet data into JSON - dealing with newline character

Tags: json, google-apps-script

In Google Sheets I have cells with text like this: `first line\nsecond line`

Obviously I want a new line character to be preserved in the json that I'm outputting, but in the json it ends up as:

```
"text": "first line\\nsecond line"
```

Here's the Apps Script:

```
var spreadsheetId = 'someId';
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId);
  var sheets = spreadsheet.getSheets();

  for (var i =  1; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    var sheet = sheets[i];
    var data = sheet.getRange(3,  1, sheet.getLastRow() -  2, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    var headers = sheet.getRange(2,  1,  1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];

    var objects = data.map(function(row) {
    var obj = {};
    for (var j =  0; j < headers.length; j++) {

      var value = (row[j] === '') ? null : row[j];

      // If the header is one of the specified ones, convert the value to a string
      if (headers[j] === 'prefs' || headers[j] === 'text') {
        if (value != null) {
          obj[headers[j]] = String(value);
        } else {
          obj[headers[j]] = value;
        }
      } else {
        // For other headers, assign the value directly
        obj[headers[j]] = value;
      }
    }
    return obj;
    });

     // Convert the array of objects to a JSON string
    var json = JSON.stringify(objects, null,  2);
    
    // Create a blob from the JSON string
    var blob = Utilities.newBlob(json, 'application/json', sheet.getName() + '.json');

    ...
```

What can I do to preserve the single `\n` in the json, so that it doesn't add the extra `\`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\n` in Google sheets is not interpreted as a new line character, but a literal forward slash `\` and a `n` character. You can either replace `\n` in sheets  with actual newline character `CHAR(10)` or replace the character in Google apps script:

```
const regex = /\\n/g;
data = data.map(r => r.map(e => String(e).replace(regex,"\n")))
```

If you only want to check say Col B(index 1, starting from 0),

```
data = data.map(r => r.map((e, i) => i === 1 ? String(e).replace(regex,"\n") : e))
```

```js
/*<ignore>*/console.config({maximize:true,timeStamps:false,autoScroll:false});/*</ignore>*/ 

const regex = /\\n/g;
let data =  [["\\n111\\n"]]
data = data.map(r => r.map(e => String(e).replace(regex,"\n")))
console.log(JSON.stringify(data[0][0]))
```

```html
<!-- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/375985/ -->    <script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: where would this line go in the script above?

Comment: @soleil after `var data=...`

Comment: the problem is, this turns every value in the json to a string. I have some columns that need to remain ints, bools, etc. I would only want to check for the new line character in column B

Comment: Check edits above.

Comment: I just noticed that this solution only catches the first `\n` in the cell. What if there are two or more?

Comment: @soleil Sorry about that. You should use ``g``lobal regex flag for multiple matches. See edited answer.

Comment: I tried the updated version with `regex` and now it's back to not catching any of them (i.e. ending up with \\n in the json whenever there's a \n in Sheets). At least using the version where I'm only checking Col B.

Comment: @soleil Ok this is embarrassing. Fixed again.

Comment: This looks like a winner!